# Startup Script Not Firing During Partial Refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a User Control, named MyUpdateControl, that fires a startup script - its HTML is simply:

```
<div id="updatableArea"></div>
```

The startup script is added in the User Control's OnLoad():

```
string doUpdateScript = String.Format(
    "DoUpdate('{0}')",
    someValue);
this.Parent.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "DoUpdateScript", doUpdateScript);
```

The MyUpdateControl User Control is sometimes contained within an Update Panel in another User Control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" >  
    <ContentTemplate>
        <UC1:MyUpdateControl ID="myUpdaterControl" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In those cases, the script is only fired when the page first loads.  It never fires during an asynchronous postback.  How can I ensure that it's also called during asynchronous postbacks?

Comment: Try UpdateMode="Conditional" for your updatepanel ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx) when registering a script within an `UpdatePanel` instead of `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. There is an overload of this method that expects the control that is registering the client script block as its first parameter.

```
public class MyUpdateControl  : Control
{
    public MyUpdateControl()
    {         
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        //..
        string doUpdateScript = String.Format(
            "DoUpdate('{0}')", someValue);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
             "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        //..
    }
}
```

The example above uses a Custom Control, i realize you are using a User Control. The two implementations are very similar but i have included an example of this below for completeness.

```
public partial class MyUpdateControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        //..
        string doUpdateScript = String.Format(
            "DoUpdate('{0}')", someValue);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
             "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        //..
    }
}
```